# Table reloadData can cause crashes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Very occasionally (once a week'ish) Crashlytics is reporting crashes such as

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

[MusicList tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

I'm wondering if these are occurring due to the data being reloaded before the table finishes rendering, so when it requests a piece of data it has been removed and not yet been re-inserted?

If this is the case, is it best to remove the `reloadData` call from `viewWillAppear` and place it in the `viewDidAppear`? But then it will be displaying potentially old data, then refreshing with the newer content which might be jarring to the end user.

This is my code so far for the controller:

```
@implementation MusicList

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitles:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [self setData:  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    dispatch_queue_t loadMusic = dispatch_queue_create("loadMusic", NULL);
    dispatch_async(loadMusic, ^{
        NSMutableDictionary * data = [Music getMusicList];

        [self setTitles:[data objectForKey:@"titles"]];
        [self setData:  [data objectForKey:@"tracks"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableMusicList reloadData];
        });
    });
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [_titles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_data[section] count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [_titles[indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"NowPlaying"]
        ? 100.0
        : 44.0;
}
```

---

**Update**: Data returned from `MusicList`:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)getMusicList {
    Db                  * db   = [[Db alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [data setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"titles"];
    [data setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"tracks"];

    if ([db prepare:@"SELECT `date`, `name` FROM `music` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 25"]) {
        NSString * date;
        NSString * name;

        while ([db stepThrough]) {
            date = [db get:0];
            name = [db get:1];

            if (date && name) {
                [[data objectForKey:@"titles"] addObject:date];
                [[data objectForKey:@"tracks"] addObject:name];
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Show the implementation of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: Sure, have added that in.

Comment: OK, I don't see any checks that `_titles` and `_data` are valid when you load the music.  Please add some asserts as this error is almost certainly data-related.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose there is a chance that could be the case. How exactly would you suggest these assertions are made?

Comment: You know the relationship between the two so write code to check every aspect of that relationship you can.  If the data is corrupt (certainly possible if the data is outside the app bundle) then you don't want to let the app crash in this way.  Better is to clear both values so the table is empty.  In any case I am certain this is cause of your crash.

Comment: I've posted the code for the `getMusicList` call. The data comes from an SQLite table bundled with the app. The data returned is from a static query, so no bound parameters. If the SQL query fails or there are no results found then a default empty `NSMutableDictionary` is returned. I'm just not sure if it is a data issue.

Comment: And if there data is not the right length?  I have told you everything I can, so over to someone else to convince you of the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code on the 10th to move the data loading into the `viewDidAppear` function and everything is now working as expected - whereas we were receiving a crash report every few days we have yet to receive a single crash in 12 days, so all's good.

I was able to reproduce the error eventually by adding a few well placed `NSLog`'s, and could see the data very occasionally finished loading before all of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`'s had run, so the error was *definitely* not what @droppy suggested in that `MusicList` was passing back corrupted data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitles:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [self setData:  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    dispatch_queue_t loadMusic = dispatch_queue_create("loadMusic", NULL);
    dispatch_async(loadMusic, ^{
        NSMutableDictionary * data = [Music getMusicList];

        [self setTitles:[data objectForKey:@"titles"]];
        [self setData:  [data objectForKey:@"tracks"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableMusicList reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your UITableView delegates, even though apple don't have documentation about the order of calls for this delegate you can always check and see which by `NSLog();` in every delegate..

in your code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    return [_titles[indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"NowPlaying"] ? 100.0: 44.0;
}
```

is dependent from another delegate

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [_titles count];
}
```

this delegate will tell the `indexPath` how many section is there, what if `heightForRowAtIndexPath` was called first before `numberOfSectionsInTableView` ??

Another, is reloading UITableView inside `-viewWillAppear`, i also dont know the reason behind this but i had that problem before and what i did was double checking the dataSource inside UITableViewDelegates like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (!_titles) // just to double check if _title is allocated and avoid `[NSNull length] error`
        _titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return [_titles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section < _data.count) // just to prevent out of bounds
         return [_data[section] count];

    return 0; // zero number of row in section if out of bounds
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section < _titles.count) // just to prevent out of bounds
        return [_titles[indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"NowPlaying"] ? 100.0 : 44.0;

    return 0;  // zero height of row in at indexPath if out of bounds
}
```

That's what i've learn from using `_titles[indexPath.section]` or something `variable[index]` in a dynamic kind of way,

ALWAYS check the BOUNDS to avoid OUT of it(BOUNDS).. Happy coding, cheers!